# Lumen/Laravel query builder - BETWEEN

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I'm attempting to convert this tradtional `sql` query to `larvael/lumen` query builder and running into brick walls.

```
$query = "SELECT a.id, a.name, a.cuisine, a.status, a.new, a.addressLine1, a.addressLine2, a.addressLine3, a.city, a.weekendot, a.weekendct, b.class
    FROM restaurants a, restaurants_class b
    WHERE a.class = b.id
    AND '$date' = CURRENT_DATE
    AND '$ntime' BETWEEN a.weekendot AND a.weekendct
    ORDER BY id DESC";
```

`$date` and `$ntime` are variables.

This is what I have so far;

```
$posts = DB::connection('web')
        ->table('restaurants')
        ->join('restaurants_class', 'restaurants.class', '=', 'restaurants_class.id')
        ->select('restaurants.*', 'restaurants_class.*')
        ->get();
```

The first `AND` statement is not getting anything from the `DB`

The second `AND` statement is comparing a `var` to two columns in the `DB`

Not sure how to implement the `whereBetween`

Answer (score 0):

This is completely untested but I think your best bet is to use `whereRaw` method as you have variables which would not allow you to use the `whereBetween` method.

I'm also assuming that the `$date` and `$ntime` variables are PHP variables and not MySQL variables.

```
$posts = DB::connection('web')
       ->table('restaurants')
       ->join('restaurants_class', 'restaurants.class', '=', 'restaurants_class.id')
       ->whereRaw('? = CURRENT_DATE', $date)
       ->whereRaw('? BETWEEN a.weekendot AND a.weekendct', $ntime)
       ->select('restaurants.*', 'restaurants_class.*')
       ->get();
```